# Unable to add a new connection to server in PostgreSQL using pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin-3

I am new to PostgreSQL and trying to configure it. After installing the PostgreSQL. I am trying to add a new connection to server using pgAdmin. I know there is a by default created on port 5432 but I change this port to 5433. And trying to configure all my database on this port. And through terminal this is working.
[image]

But when I am trying to add a new connection to a server it throws

```
09:56:56: Error: Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "tars"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "tars"
```

I have already followed this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres). And also tried configuring pg_hba.conf. Changed this line

```
local   all             all                                     peer
```

to

```
local   all             all                                     md5
```

But couldn't add a new connection.
This is the screenshot, the way I am trying to configure 
[image]

Can someone help me to create a new server ? And also help me to understand this little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem like you are connection via termial to port 5432 as command psql on terminal directly connect to **default port 5432**

Try connecting to database via terminal using below

```
psql -p 5433
```

After connected, change user password

```
alter role tars with password 'tars'; --if role in not present create one with create role tar with superuser; 
alter role tars with login;
```

now go to pgadmin and change the following :

```
on maintenance db put "postgres"
on user put "tar"
on password put "tar"
```

and try connecting if still kindly lemme know the below things :

1) Can u list contents of pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf file ?

2) Also how u changed port number via postgresql.conf or created another cluster ?

Comment: This is really a stupid thing from my side. All the configurations and settings were correct. It just I always forget to restart the postgresql after making any changes in that. That's why it was not reflecting any changes. Thank you @Ashiq for your time and answer. +1

Comment: @Lokesh we learn from our mistake thats why we called as humans don't restart postgresql every time when u make changes only to variables like listen_address,port etc then only restart else reload will work